# docker subdomain api.localhost works on chrome but not in terminal

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm running a Laravel + Laradock stack and it is working fine in Chrome.

- http://localhost shows my home route from `web.php`
- http://api.localhost shows my home route from `api.php`

However, I copied a curl command to try from console:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://api.localhost/test \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: a47e7afb-fcc0-4c80-87ec-f00da14e5f7c'
```

And it returns:

```
ping: cannot resolve api.localhost: Unknown host
```

Removing the sub-domain it works fine.

is this an issue with Docker or Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding sub-domains to `/etc/hosts` file